# A swipe on status bar opens on quick setting instead of notifcation panel

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, notification-bar

In short: any idea how to set a swipe on the status bar to open the notification panel, not the quick settings one? (It was the default setting before I installed/uninstalled an app)

The whole story:
Samsung Galaxy SIII 4G GT-i9305, Android 4.4.4, **rooted**
Nova launcher

Xposed messed up my settings. Before I intalled this app the notification panel, was fine, it opened the notification panel by default (not the quick setting one). So I had this panel:

[image: Notification S-3]

Now when I open the notification panel, it opens on the quick setting panel so I have to click on the lines icon (top right) to get back to the notification panel.

This is annoying. I did restart, pull the battery, restart, pull the battery, but the change made by Xposed remains: my notification panel open on the quick setting panel. See here:

[image: Notification Panel]

**I'm not looking for an app**, but the right file I should edit to get back the settings I had before installing stickmount. **Any idea what files could have been edited, could keep this setting modification even after uninstalling the app?**

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT: in Safe Mode, the problem is solved because the Xposed update is removed**

Comment: CM has an option like this called Smart Settings which opens quick settings when swiped from the right of the screen. Maybe you have something set up like that as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Putting the phone in Safe Mode](https://youtu.be/zkSbmKYvBtQ?t=48s) (when swipe down in the status bar, it open the notification panel)
2. Restart the phone in normal mode

If this doesn't work, first go in recovery mode and swipe cache and then redo the 2 steps above.

The safe mode actually remove the Xposed update, so I can't have both Xposed and the notification panel with a simple swipe.

P.S: I didn't try Adem answer (I don't have a backup of the build.prop).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's some **TouchWiz bug** and if you can't figure out what's wrong, you could use a third party app called [Color Status Bar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thirstystar.colorstatusbar&hl=en). 
It has some themes built-in for notification panels.
Or you could also have a look at some modded TouchWiz-like notification app in this [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2212470)

**EDIT:**
If the issue is solved in Safe mode, then its evidence that downloaded app caused the phone to behave that way.
Safemode allows you to boot up your device with only the core pre-loaded applications running, meaning any apps you’ve downloaded won’t be running.
Copy the build.prop to external sdcard when in safemode and compare it with the build.prop when the issue occured. That will give some insight on  ​why it might've occured.
Restore that build.prop, if the issue is still not solved in Normal mode.

Comment: Thanks for this, I did what you say. When Color Status Bar is active, the panel open first on Notification but the notification doesn't have all the settings I had on the original notification (so it's no a good solution). Also I am very dependent on my battery so the less app of this kind I have, the better it is. Uninstalling Color Status Bar didn't revert the notification panel to the default. (It's not uninstalling StickMount that caused the problem it's installing it, unfortunately uninstalling StickMount didn't revert to the default behavior)

Answer (score 1):

Try to restore your `build.prop` to original. Worked for me.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind it?

Comment: I don't know, but I had the same issue. I tried everything, and this was the one thing that helped.

Comment: Thanks Adem! I don't have a backup of the build.prop and I could solve  the problem by going into Safe Mode (see selected answer)

Answer (score 1):

If you Nova launcher Prime, check whether swipe down gesture is attributed to Quick settings or not.

Nova Settings -> Gestures & Inputs -> Swipe down.

Comment: Thanks but this is only available  with Nova Prime (paid version). Putting the phone in Safe Mode resolve the problem.